# SSRS - Logon failed (rsLogonFailed)

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have two servers : A and B, with absolutly the same version of my report.
I have full access to A, but only read-access on B.

On the B server, I have the message: Logon failed (rsLogonFailed). 
But it's all clear on the A side.
In order to understand the problem, I need to reproduce the same error on A.

I tried a lot of modifications : 
- Wrong credentials for the data source.
- Turning off the reporting service.
- Messing with the data source properties ...

It seems like I can't reproduce the same message.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What type of authentication are you using when accessing the reporting services?

Comment: I am using a Windows authentification for the reporting service, and Database credentials to connect to the data source.

Btw, I think that's a data source related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Actually it was some stupid human beeing (sorry for that, but this one deserves it) who entered a wrong password for the data source at B (the one which I can't fully access), without notifying any body.

Last point that may help you some day, the thing that fooled me, was that the error message is different for users and admins !